# Bootstrap date-time picker calendar widget is not docked on the date button i.e. the calendar widget doesn't scrolls up/down with the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a web application in which I am using the bootstrap date-time picker to select a date in any form.
Everything is working fine but the only problem is that on clicking the date button, the calendar widget appears on the screen beside the date button but on scrolling the form up/down, the calendar widget doesn't scroll up/down with the page. My requirement is that the calendar widget should be docked on the date button and should scroll up/down with the button field on scrolling the page up/down.

Please suggest me the changes I should do to get the desired behavior.

Thanks in advance,
Abhinav

Comment: PLease share your code

Comment: There are several plugins called bootstrap-date-time-picker. Maybe you mix something here. Knowing exactly which bootstrap version and which plugin is used would be an advantage.